# I recieve an "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" when I'm trying to change a time format

Tags: python, strftime

When i use %H:%M:%S i get the error given below.
If im using it with dots everything is fine. Can someone explain why? and how to use colons?

Here is the code:

```
import os, time, zipfile

source = ["C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Documents\\Projects", "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Pictures\\pics"]
target_dir = 'D:\\Backup'

today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

comment = input('Enter a comment: ')
com = comment.replace(' ', '_') + '.zip'

now = time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d. %H:%M:%S')

if not os.path.exists(today):
    os.mkdir(today)
    print('Folder made successfully')

if len(comment) == 0: 
    target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'

else: 
    target = today + os.sep + now + '_' + com 

z = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w' )

def zip(c):
    for a in c:
        for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(a):
            for file in files:
                z.write(os.path.join(folder, file))
         
zip(source)

z.close()
```

And here is the traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Programming\backupscript.py", line 38, in <module>
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(target, 'w' )
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1249, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\Backup\\2022.11.04\\2022.11.04. 16:59:39_wa_w.zip'
```

Comment: The colon is an invalid character in Windows paths.

Comment: Actually it's disallowed on Windows.  Works fine on a Mac.

Comment: @JohnGordon I still live in the good old days before OS X ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `:` on Windows is restricted. Also, the following are reserved characters:

- `<` (less than)
- `>` (greater than)
- `"` (double quote)
- `/` (forward slash)
- `\` (backslash)
- `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
- `?` (question mark)
- `*` (asterisk)

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)